# Stop redirecting in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi am developing a webpart which is included in sharepoint app and I need to stop redirection in some cases. But it doesn't work, i am trying to use

```
$('a').click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                return false;
            });
```

it executes and anyway redirection is done. How can I break it?

Purpose of it is: when user change sth on page I need to ask if he wants to proceed or not and then stop any redirection from othe links he might clicked.

Edit:
I just checked and with regular a with links inside it works but the problem is with link like this:

```
<a title="Delivery And Technology" class="ms-cui-ctl-large" id="someId" role="button" onclick="return false;" href="javascript:;" unselectable="on" mscui:controltype="" jQuery182001210093900916337="93">
```

which has inside this html

```
<SPAN class=ms-cui-ctl-largeIconContainer unselectable="on"><SPAN class=" ms-cui-img-32by32 ms-cui-img-cont-float ms-cui-imageDisabled" unselectable="on"><IMG style="TOP: -96px; LEFT: -160px" alt="Delivery And Technology" src="/_layouts/1033/images/ps32x32.png" unselectable="on"></SPAN></SPAN><SPAN class=ms-cui-ctl-largelabel unselectable="on">Delivery And<BR>Technology</SPAN>
```

so seems that when I click on this java script recognize it and redirects me so what i want to achive is to detect it and stop before it will redirect me to other page.

Comment: What do you mean with redirection? Do you want to block the user from following links?

Comment: start by including jQuery and sticking your code in document.ready. You only need the first one, preventDefault(), to prevent the default action of an anchor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will prevent dynamically added anchors from navigating too:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
     return false;
});
```

steveukx suggested shorthand:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', false);
```

Comment: You can also use the shorthand of `$(document).on('click', 'a', false);`

Comment: @karaxuna the problem is that this a element has id and redirection is binded in java script with this id, and i can't modify it casuse it is from sharepoint, so what I am looking is to stop all actions on DOM

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you run this code before the DOM is ready. Try wrap it in a [DOM-ready callback](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(function () {
    $('a').click(function(event){
        return false;
    });
});
```

*Note that returning false is equivalent to `.preventDefault()` and `.stopImmediatePropagation()` together, so just returning false will be sufficient. In your case it might be more appropriate to just use `.preventDefault()` and nothing else though.*

Answer (score 0):

If the element has a had a handler attached before your code executes, it isn't possible to reliably remove or prevent the handler from running.

Assuming you have `jQuery` available, and you are running this function after the element has been added to the DOM and had its handlers attached you can replace it with an identical element:

```
jQuery('a').replaceWith(function(index, innerHTML) {
  return jQuery(this.cloneNode(false)).html(innerHTML);
});
```