# Website Redirection Fix?

Tags: redirect, plugins, web

I run an anime website with embeded links for players, multiple per page/per episode so I have quite a few, and on some of the pages, the players are redirecting the user to adultfriendfinder, which is very annoying because it doesn't redirect them through a popup or a new tab, it redirects my site to their page, and this happens even with adblock.

here is a link to my website, and a page that will display this:

http://animewolf.tv/anime/death-note-episode-1-dubbed/

if you click on 'mp4upload' it will redirect to adultfriendfinder.com, you'll need to press back and play the video, which is very annoying.

If it doesn't redirect you and you want to see, just look around the site's episodes ( http://animewolf.tv/watch-anime/ )

Is there anything I can do to get around this? any plugin, anything I can do to block the site? anything?

thx.

Comment: Have you looked at the PHP code that gets called when you click that control?

Answer (score 0):

if you see from the firebug, i find network error (404) in `http://www.myanimelinks.com/nanotabs.js` which redirect you to google-ads(adsense). It is known that if no proper ads exists based on your site will force google to redirect the ads to other ads or blank (and google dislike ads inside a frame.

Besides, links to access `http://www.myanimelinks.com/nanotabs.js` is denied, blocked or redirect to 404 page.
if you access this following link> without frame, everything is going well:

```
http://animewolf.tv/wp-content/plugins/anime/embed/auengine.php?id=e5XVDRmg
```

In this case, you should remove other links available which causes error.

UPDATE:1

this links > `http://animewolf.tv/wp-content/plugins/anime/video_source.php?source=YToxOntpOjA7YTozOntzOjI6ImlkIjtzOjEyOiI2aGMzY2w1b3NjZzkiO3M6NDoidHlwZSI7czoxOiI5IjtzOjY6Im51bWJlciI7czoxOiI3Ijt9fQ==` go to encrypted page content then you add it to your page within frame. this causes this.

now try to add this link > **`http://animewolf.tv/wp-content/plugins/anime/embed/auengine.php?id=e5XVDRmg`** directly to the src="" of your frame. perhaps, it can work.

UPDATE:2

Try this and place on your page which globally relate to them:

```
<script>
$(document.body).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
     return false;
});
});
</script>
```

otherwise, see this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811079/stop-redirecting-in-javascript
```

Comment: So I should remove the auengine links? is that what is causing this?

Comment: I removed the AUEngine player completely and it's still doing it apparently, is there any other solution? I'm not sure if all the players have it embedded, is there anyway I can remove the jsfile that's accessing it? I'm sorry i'm quite new to this but I'm trying to figure out what the root cause is and the plugin is encrypted so I can't access it directly

Comment: Is it possible for me to just block the redirect?

Comment: have you already change the link to the direct link I wrote above (UPDATE)? how is it now?
# as long as you use other links into your site, it's impossible, sorry

Comment: I see it, but the problem is that will only do it for that one page/episode link. I need it to do for all of them (over 30,000) and also the plugin's core files are encrypted so I don't have access to that. Is there a way I can simply block the redirect?

Comment: Well thanks anyway I suppose, I'm still going to search for an alternative though :)

Comment: Ok :) thank you I tried it. however the popups don't come up for me anymore, so I'll need to wait and check to see if it happens to others. unless you can check for me, but that's up to you. Thank you though, I really appreciate the effort trying to help me :)))